# Simple Alloy constraint doesn't work as expected

Tags: alloy

The following model produces instances with exactly 2 address relations when the number of Books is limited to 1, however, if more Books are allowed it will create instances with 0-3 address relations. My misunderstanding of how Alloy works?

```
sig Name{}
sig Addr{}
sig Book { addr: Name -> lone Addr }
pred show(b:Book) { #b.addr = 2 } 
// nr. of address relations in every Book should be 2
run show for 3 but 2 Book 
// works as expected with 1 Book
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of `show` should include one Book, labeled as being the `b` of `show`, which has two address pairs.  But `show` does not say that *every* book must have two address pairs, only that at least one must have two address pairs.

[Postscript]

When you ask Alloy to show you an instance of a predicate, for example by the command `run show`, then Alloy should show you an instance:  that is (quoting section 5.2.1 of *Software abstractions*, which you already have open) "an assignment of values to the variables of the constraint for which the constraint evaluates to true."  In any given universe, there may be many other possible assignments of values to the variables for which the constraint evaluates to false; the existence of such possible non-suitable assignments is unavoidable in any universe with more than one atom.

Informally, we can think of a `run` command for a predicate P with arguments X, Y, Z as requesting that Alloy show us universes which satisfy the expression

```
some X, Y, Z : univ | P[X, Y, Z]
```

The `run` command does *not* amount to the expression

```
all X, Y, Z : univ | P[X, Y, Z]
```

If you want to see only universes in which *every* book has two pairs in its `addr` relation, then say so:

```
pred all_books_have_2 { all b : Book | #b.addr = 2 }
```

I think it's better that `run` have implicit existential quantification, rather than implicit universal quantification.  One way to see why is to imagine a model that defines trees, such as:

```
sig Node { parent : lone Node }
fact parent_acyclic { no n : Node | n in n.^parent }
```

Suppose we get tired of seeing universes in which every tree is trivial and contains a single node.  I'd like to be able to define a predicate that guarantees at least one tree with depth greater than 1, by writing

```
pred nontrivial[n : Node]{ some n.parent }
```

Given the constraint that trees be acyclic, there can never be a non-empty universe in which the predicate `nontrivial` holds for all nodes. So if `run` and `pred` had the semantics you have been supposing, we could not use `nontrivial` to find universes containing non-trivial trees.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's a quote from Software Abstractions: "An **instance** is an example: a scenario in which **both the facts and the predicate hold.**". When this model is executed there will be some solution instances where the **predicate does not hold**. Isn't there a contradiction?

Comment: If a universe has at least one atom of signature `Book` that satisfies the `show` predicate, the predicate holds for that atom. Is Alloy showing you universes in which no book at all satisfies `show`? If you want the constraint to hold for all books, you need to say so:  `pred all_books_have_2 { all b : Book | #b.addr = 2 }`.  Each universe shown you as an example by Alloy has at least one assignment of values to the arguments of the predicate `show` that makes it true; there is no claim that the predicate must be true of all atoms.

Comment: Mr. C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, your very clear postscript explanation has helped me a lot to correct my view on how Alloy predicates are handled. Thank you very much.